# Add name | Rename a java method using annotaion

Tags: java, annotations

I'm searching for a solution to get two name for one method using Java Annotation. I need something like this :

```
@SOMETHING(name="Method_Name_2")
public String methodName1(String arg){
    // Some code
    return var;
}
```

and when I call the method

```
obj.Method_Name_2(arg)
```

or

```
obj.methodName1(arg)
```

I need that the two call execute the same method.

Comment: [ask] "Searching for a solution" = looking for a library? That is off-topic on SO. This question seems to be too broad too (in its current form), unless you show some of your code and explain where did you get stuck.

Comment: Why you need annotations. why not ´public String Method_Name_2(String arg1) {return methodName1(arg1);}`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot provide two different names for a method in java.
 However you can wrap original method inside new method name:

```
public String Method_Name_2(String arg){
    return methodName1(arg);
}
```

Comment: smart answer! XD but you are not using annotations

Comment: Thx but I needt something to improve Sonar metrics for an existing project which has many method with "_".

Comment: @BENYOUSSEFHamza Getting "better" metrics without actually improving the code is not what I would call a judicious change.